# How to establish convergence and find limit of the sequence$(n+1)^{1/\ln(n+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to establish convergence and find limit of the sequence $(n+1)^{1/\ln(n+1)}$.

I'd add some details
We are given a sequence 
$(n+1)^{1/\ln(n+1)}$
And are supposed to prove that this sequence is convergent and also find the limit of the sequence. If there's any other detail required, please ask.

Edit 2: I have attempted to solve similar questions only by squeeze theorem. Fot instance, I found the limit of n^(1/n^2) by relating it to n^(1/n) and 1 and then used squeeze theorem. It hasn't worked here.

Comment: Why is it urgent...?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Take the logarithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. We have 
$$ \log(n+1)^{1/{\log(n+1)}} = \frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n+1)} = 1 $$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used to believe you can't use logarithm on both sides because the properties haven't been proven. With a little bit of google-ing, I realized I was wrong.